# How to redirect to a URL in Laravel if a specific URL is called?

Tags: php, url, laravel

I want to define a route in Laravel 4.x if a URL is called f.e:

```
http://myurl.com/images/*.png
```

If this url is called a redirect to the following URL should be made:

```
http://myurl.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that should work..

```
Route::get('/images/{all}.png', function()
{
    return Redirect::to('/');
});
```